# Is it safe to run with thunder storms overhead in an overcast sky when you live near saltwater?

Tags: running, training, long-distance-running, running-training-plan

I want to run and need to know this to be able to get some runs in to keep on schedule. I haven't grown up near the gulf or ocean, so I dont know how close to the truth this is. Sometimes when there are lots thunderstorms overhead such that there are no space between them (overcast) the lightning seems to only hit the saltwater.

In this very specific case is it true that the lightning will only the saltwater and is slightly safer to run?

It seems to make sense electrically since cloud to cloud plus cloud to saltwater are lower resistance paths to more sources of static charge.

---

All day today in Pinellas County Florida the lightning stayed confined to the water, but about mid-day the pan handle had a slew of lightning strikes that appeared only on land. Unfortunately its impossible to know if it was overcast and stretched over both water and land.

---

*--Deleted rant against closing votes--*

---

The answer is no because weather changes too quickly for a 1-2 hour run.

Even though the lightning map shows that all the lightning is restrained to the water for hours on end sometimes it changes and starts going on land without any obvious reason for it on any radar or any view of the same overcast sky.

Comment: I think this would be better on outdoors.stackexchange.com. There's a lot of info about lightning that's better suited over there.

Comment: @Blam The sand is saturated with saltwater so its not exactly dry nonconductive land :)

Comment: @EricKaufman I want answers from people who run. Not hiking or walking because those activities dont rely on a steady training program.

Comment: Lightning is a serious problem in many parts of the world and it is much more relevant than a training program. I'm a sar volunteer myself and definitely learned most of my lightning knowledge in wilderness medicine, not athletics.

Comment: @EricKaufman Thanks Eric, but Ive heard many times that people will go for a run in lightning and have myself living up north. In Florida, or any coastal area, where everything is so flat and lightning so much more abundant I am much more keen not to do this. I want to know what other runners do.

Comment: Fair enough, but especially Florida which is so lightning active  (tied with summers in the Rockies I think) I'd pick the brains about folks who know what to do, lessening postures, signs before strikes, strike types, etc. I was personally surprised to learn that people are much more likely to be killed by lightning (area dependent ) than anything else outdoors.

Comment: @EricKaufman Thanks, maybe this should be the answer for now. Besides it is the non-opinion based kind of answer thats best for these kinds of safety related questions. Could you point to some data showing area dependence if you enter it in as an answer?

Comment: Lightnings striking people are not uncommon at all. I would take the thing seriously. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MNJRPOltifI

Comment: @Mephisto Who said Im not taking it serious?

Comment: @Blam Only runners because of the training schedule which includes nearly daily runs. Didnt say a walker has a different risk profile. Im not being  combative here. I have seen a lightning map show strikes that stay on water all day long while I wait to run, so I'd like to know if other people have seen this and take advantage of it. Pretty simple.

Comment: @Blam I have seen a lightning map show strikes that stay on water all day long while I wait to run, so I'd like to know if other people have seen this and take advantage of it. Pretty simple. Actually very straight forward.

Comment: @Jason - I see your reopen request. But unfortunately, this issue is not directly related to exercise, but is a question of general physics. And the answer is largely dependent on very small geographic areas. For instance, you have a lower risk of getting struck in a metropolitan area, than you do in a field or on the beach.

Comment: @Alec Thanks for the feedback but this is a training hazard that only runners can answer but more importantly this is a question on running training program. I know the physics (electrically at least) so I know anything is possible but experience is the best guide. Seems the answer is limited but if left open eventually someone will answer. Till then there is at least a safety answer from Eric, so I think the question/answer is value added to the site. Thanks and please reconsider.

Comment: @Alec Its ok to recommend types of shoes (minimalist vs traditional) to run in but not what environment is ok to run in?

Answer (score 1):

Just to provide some background, lightning is a real problem and causes a lot of casualties. From [Medicine for Mountaineering, 6th Edition](http://amzn.to/1MbwZKi):

> Lightning was the second most common cause of weather-related death
>   over the forty-year period from 1962 to 2002. Only floods, many of
>   which are also produced by thunderstorms, killed more people during
>   this time. Lightning kills more people than hurricanes and tornados
>   combined. During the ten-year period 1940 through 1949 approximately
>   330 people were killed each year by lightning in the United States.
>   Now, approximately one hundred people lose their lives that way each
>   year. Of equal note, however, only about 10 percent of the individuals
>   hit by lightning are killed. The remaining 90 percent may suffer
>   long-lasting injuries or disabilities, and lightning may even have a
>   lifetime impact.

When lightning is around, you really aren't safe anywhere:

> The spot where lightning is going to strike is not determined until
>   the bolt is about 30 meters from the ground or object. Shorter objects
>   may be struck even though a taller object is nearby. Associated step
>   voltages and surface arcs may be fatal more than 40 meters from the
>   initial strike point.

Specifically related to Florida, [the Journal of Environmental Health had an article which went into some state and regional statistics](http://stats.bls.gov/iif/oshwc/cfoi/jeh5_05_45-50.pdf):

> Rhode Island, North Dakota, Hawaii, Delaware, and
>   Alaska did not record any incidents during the period. Twenty-two
>   states recorded one to five deaths; 14 states recorded six to 10
>   deaths; and 10 states recorded ≥10 deaths (Table 2). Texas (32 deaths)
>   and Florida (49 deaths) together accounted for 22 percent of
>   fatalities.

The biggest piece of advice I could offer up is the [30-30 rule](http://www.lightningman.com.au/safety_procedures.html#4). Lightning moves 1 mile in 5 seconds. If the flash-to-bang time is less than 30 seconds, you are in an active lightning area and should seek appropriate shelter until the storm has passed for more than 30 minutes. Most deaths and injuries occur after the rain is done and the threat of the storm seems to have passed.

In places like Florida, New Mexico, and the Rockies where lightning is a way of life it's pretty common for people to be relaxed and complacement. But again, these are the places where most people get killed or seriously injured for life, so just because someone's gotten away with dangerous behavior doesn't mean it's a good idea.

Some decent shelters for someone running down roads and cross country:

- Under a bridge, overpass, or tunnel. Don't stand by any metal.
- In a car, with the windows rolled up. Only a hardtop, no convertibles / soft tops.
- Underneath high voltage electrical lines. Keep at least 50' away from the metal towers. The towers and lines are designed to handle lightning strikes and carry the current deep underground.

Comment: Wouldn't the use of shoes with rubber protect you too?

Comment: @Freedom not if the shoes and you are wet :)

Comment: @Freedo, the lightning bolt has just punched through several miles of non-conductive air.  What makes you think an inch of non-conductive rubber will stop it?